# forループを使ってリストのstringを大文字にする際に、新たなリストは必要ですか？

Tags: python

forループを使って以下のように実行するとうまく結果が出ました。

**コード**

```
l=["Mon","tue","Wed","sat"]
b=[]
for a in l:
     a=a.upper()
     b.append(a)
print(b)
```

**実行結果**

```
'MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'SAT'
```

しかし、以下のようにlist bをのぞいてprint(l)とすると、以下の実行結果となりました。
なぜこのような違いになるのでしょうか？
リストの中のstringを変数aに入れて大文字に処理をした後、新たにリストを作る必要があるのでしょうか？

**コード**

```
l=["Mon","tue","Wed","sat"]

for a in l:
     a=a.upper()
print(l)
```

**実行結果**

```
'Mon', 'tue', 'Wed', 'sat'
```

Comment: 参考: [In-place modification of Python lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51804790/in-place-modification-of-python-lists)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**回答**

> なぜこのような違いになるのでしょうか？

`a=a.upper()`において代入前の`a`はリスト`l`の要素を示していましたが、`a.upper()`はリスト`l`とは無関係なオブジェクトです。代入によって`a`はリスト`l`の要素を示さなくなっただけで、リスト`l`は変化しません。

> 新たにリストを作る必要があるのでしょうか？

リスト`l`の要素を置き換えれば、新たなリストは必要ありません。

```
for i in range(len(l)):
    l[i] = l[i].upper()
```

---

### コード

```
l=["Mon","tue","Wed","sat"]

for i in range(len(l)):
     l[i] = l[i].upper()

print(l)
```

### 結果

```
['MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'SAT']
```

Comment: 回答頂きありがとうございます。l=["Mon","tue","Wed","sat"]
for i in range(len(l)):
l[i] = l[i].upper()
l=l[i]
print(l)

Comment: このように実行したところ、以下のエラーが出ました。 l[i] = l[i].upper()
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: すみません。バグでした。lengthをlenに修正しました。